# 403 Forbidden error when making an ajax Post request in Django framework

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, post

I am trying to integrate jquery into a web application I am making with Django framework. I am however having a hard time trying to make a simple `ajax` call to work. My template file that contains the form html and javascript to handle the ajax call looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$( "#target" ).submit(function() {
console.log('Form was submitted');
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/hello/",  // or just url: "/my-url/path/"
        data: {
            query: $( "#query" ).val()   
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
return false;
  });   
  })
</script>
<form id="target" action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %}
 <input id= "query" type="text" value="Hello there">
 <input type="submit" value="Search Recent Tweets">
</form>
```

My `views.py` that is supposed to handle the ajax call looks like:

```
 from django.core.context_processors import csrf
 from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
 from django.template.loader import get_template
 from django.template import Context,RequestContext
 from django.views.decorators.csrf import ensure_csrf_cookie
 from django.http import HttpResponse

 # access resource
 def hello(request):
  c = {}
  c.update(csrf(request))
  if request.is_ajax():
        t = get_template('template.html')
        #html = t.render(Context({'result': 'hello world'}))
        con = RequestContext(request, {'result': 'hello world'})
        return render_to_response('template.html', c, con)
  else:
        return HttpResponse('Not working!')
```

I have tried to follow the official documentation on [Cross-Site Request Forgery Protection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ref-contrib-csrf) and also looked at several stackoverflow questions addressing a similar problem. I have included the `{% csrf_token %}` in my `html` template file but it still doesn't seem to be working. I get an error in the console suggesting that the ajax call failed:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/ 403 (FORBIDDEN)
```

How do I pass the `result` variable along with my http response and get the ajax call to work smoothly? Any help is deeply appreciated.

**Edit-1**

I wasn't supposedly passing the `csrf` token along with my post request. SO as per the documentation I added the following code to my template javascript:

```
function getCookie(name) {
var cookieValue = null;
if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
        // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
        if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
            cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
            break;
        }
    }
}
    return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
console.log(csrftoken);

//Ajax call
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
// these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
$.ajaxSetup({
    crossDomain: false, // obviates need for sameOrigin test
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type)) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

When I refresh the template html page in the browser, I get `null` in the console, suggesting that the cookie is not set or not defined. What am I missing?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Because you did not post the **csrfmiddlewaretoken**, so Django forbid you.
[this document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax) can help you.

Comment: I have updated my question as per your suggestion. I still get the same error. I would appreciate if you can tell me how you got it working.

Comment: "csrfmiddlewaretoken" is a key in your posted data,for example,when you need to ajax login,your posted data may like this: {'username':'username','password':'password','csrfmiddlewaretoken':'CSRF-TOKEN-VALUE'}

Comment: Thanks @PYTY, that was the problem. I wasn't embedding the token.

Comment: your link not work, link changed to this : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax

Comment: i know this has been a while, but does this still hold true even if you've disabled csrf middleware in settings.py?

Answer (score 28):

For the lazy guys:

First download cookie: http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/

Add it to your html:

```
<script src="{% static 'designer/js/jquery.cookie.js' %}"></script>
```

Now you can create a working POST request:

```
var csrftoken = $.cookie('csrftoken');

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});

$.ajax(save_url, {
    type : 'POST',
    contentType : 'application/json',
    data : JSON.stringify(canvas),
    success: function () {
        alert("Saved!");
    }

})
```

Comment: I followed the above code and I can now send ajax() post, but it does not read my data/parameters. Example data: {"name":"John Birada"}. The name parameter is always null. thanks

Answer (score 12):

The fastest solution if you are not embedding js into your template is:

Put `<script type="text/javascript"> window.CSRF_TOKEN = "{{ csrf_token }}"; </script>` before your reference to script.js file in your template, then add `csrfmiddlewaretoken` into your `data` dictionary:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: somepathname + "do_it/",
            data: {csrfmiddlewaretoken: window.CSRF_TOKEN},
            success: function() {
                console.log("Success!");
            }
        })
```

If you do embed your js into the template, it's as simple as: `data: {csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'}`

Comment: very good and simple solution, thanks man

Answer (score 7):

I find all previous answers on-spot but let's put things in context.

The 403 forbidden response comes from the CSRF middleware (see [Cross Site Request Forgery protection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/)):

> By default, a ‘403 Forbidden’ response is sent to the user if an incoming request fails the checks performed by CsrfViewMiddleware.

Many options are available. I would recommend to follow the [answer of @fivef](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26100613/940098) in order to make jQuery add the `X-CSRFToken` header before every AJAX request with `$.ajaxSetup`.

This answer requires the cookie jQuery plugin. If this is not desirable, another possibility is to add:

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
```

BUT: if the setting [`CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-httponly) is set to True, which often happens as the [Security middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/middleware/#module-django.middleware.security) recommends so, then the cookie is not there, even if `@ensure_csrf_cookie()` is used. In this case `{% csrf_token %}` must be provided in every form, which produces an output such as `<input name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="cr6O9...FUXf6" type="hidden">`. So the `csrfToken` variable would simply be obtained with:

```
var csrftoken = $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val();
```

Again `$.ajaxSetup` would be required of course.

Other options which are available but **not recommended** are to disable the middleware or the csrf protection for the specific form with `@csrf_exempt()`.

Comment: Finally figured out what was going on through your comment. They should definitely add this to the csrf ajax docs. I had no idea that `CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY` was breaking my ajax posts.

Answer (score 6):

```
data: {"csrfmiddlewaretoken" : "{{csrf_token}}"}
```

You see "403 (FORBIDDEN)", because you don`t send "csrfmiddlewaretoken" parameter.
In template each form has this: {% csrf_token %}.
You should add "csrfmiddlewaretoken" to your ajax data dictionary. My example is sending "product_code" and "csrfmiddlewaretoken" to app "basket" view "remove":

```
$(function(){
    $('.card-body').on('click',function(){
        $.ajax({
          type: "post",
          url: "{% url 'basket:remove'%}",
          data: {"product_code": "07316", "csrfmiddlewaretoken" : "{{csrf_token}}" }
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: Hi AndrewPt, please consider explaining what exactly you've done, or minimally provide an explanation of what your code does so that people who read the code understand what you're doing exactly. Thanks!

Comment: Hi,  Vishrut Mavani, I`ve added an explanation!

Comment: perfect and straightforward answer

Answer (score 2):

To set the cookie, use the [`ensure_csrf_cookie`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.ensure_csrf_cookie) decorator in your view:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import ensure_csrf_cookie

@ensure_csrf_cookie
def hello(request):
    code_here()
```

Comment: And you have the middleware `'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'`, in MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES in your settings.py`?

Comment: Yes, @kelvinss, I had made the necessary changes in settings.py

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you aren't caching the page/view that your form is showing up on. It could be caching your CSRF_TOKEN. Happened to me!

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to add X-CSRFTOKEN header with the "{{ csrf_token }}" value like in the following example:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "{% url 'register_lowresistancetyres' %}",
            type: "POST",
            headers: {//<==
                        "X-CSRFTOKEN": "{{ csrf_token }}"//<==
                },
            data: $(example_form).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                //Success code
            },
            error: function () {
                //Error code
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try including this decorator on your dispatch code

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt     
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
     return super(LessonUploadWorkView,self).dispatch(request,*args,**kwargs)
```

Comment: csrf_exempt is not recommended

Answer (score 0):

With SSL/https and with CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False, I still don't have csrftoken in the cookie, either using the *getCookie(name)* function proposed in [django Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/) or the *jquery.cookie.js* proposed by [fivef](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26100613/7639622).

[Wtower](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30210391/7639622) summary is perfect and I thought it would work after removing CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY from settings.py but it does'nt in https!

**Why csrftoken is not visible in document.cookie???**

Instead of getting

> "django_language=fr; csrftoken=rDrGI5cp98MnooPIsygWIF76vuYTkDIt"

I get only

> "django_language=fr"

WHY? Like [SSL/https removes X-CSRFToken from headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42536254/ssl-https-removes-x-csrftoken-from-headers) I thought it was due to the proxy header params of Nginx but apparently not... Any idea?

Unlike [django doc Notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/), it seems impossible to work with csrf_token in cookies with https. The only way to pass csrftoken is through the DOM by using {% csrf_token %} in html and get it in jQuery by using

```
var csrftoken = $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val();
```

It is then possible to pass it to ajax either by header ([xhr.setRequestHeader](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43776020/7639622)), either by [params](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6170377/7639622).

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

template.html

```
  $.ajax({
    url: "{% url 'XXXXXX' %}",
    type: 'POST',
    data: {modifica: jsonText, "csrfmiddlewaretoken" : "{{csrf_token}}"},
    traditional: true,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(result){
       window.location.href = "{% url 'XXX' %}";
        }
});
```

view.py

```
def aggiornaAttivitaAssegnate(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        richiesta = json.loads(request.POST.get('modifica'))
```

Answer (score -3):

You must change your folder chmod 755 and file(.php ,.html) chmod 644.