# Request not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I am very new to AJAX and I made a simple test to see if I can get AJAX working.

If I press the like button, the server should increment 1 like and respond with the latest like count by alerting the user.

Now, I get an alert saying 'error'. It is now raising a 404

Looks like AJAX request has failed. Why is this happening?

**index.html** (partial)

```
<div>
   {{ cmt.body }}<br/>
   <strong>
       <span class="like_count" style="color:green">{{cmt.likes}}</span>
       <button type="button" class="like_btn" data-cmt_id="{{ cmt.id }}">Like</button>
   </strong>
</div>
```

**views.py**

```
def update_like(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        try:
            cmt = Comment.objects.get(pk=int(request.POST['cmid']))
            cmt.likes += 1
            cmt.save()
        except KeyError:
            return HttpResponse('Error')

        return HttpResponse(cmt.likes)
```

**default.js** (imported in base.html which index.html extends)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.like_btn').on('click', function(){
            var comment = $(this).attr('data-cmt_id');
            $.ajax({
                url: '/comment/update_like',
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    cmid: comment
                },
                success: function(data){
                    alert("!!"+data);
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
        })
    });
```

Addition:::

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', index),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    url(r'^comment/update_like/$', update_like)
)
```

Comment: Isn't the method name is /comment/update_like instead of /comment/like ?

Comment: Wow.. I'm such an idiot.... thanks for the note :) But now I get a popup with 'error'

Comment: What error? edit your question.

Comment: It's hard to help without debug information. Please use your browsers javascript console and check the server response and the message of jquery. They will help a lot.

Comment: Change url(r'^comment/like/$', update_like) to url(r'^comment/update_like/$', update_like)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally managed to fix this issue.

First of all thanks to **mrcrgl**.  I looked around for a debug console that gave me detailed information and turns out IE network tab provides extensive detail :)

The initial problem was identified by looking at response body which was a error page for not putting a '/' at the end of the js url.

It should have been

```
 url: '/comment/update_like/'
```

not,

```
 url: '/comment/update_like'
```

After this, I got a 403 Forbidden. Quick google search gave me this

[403 Forbidden error when making an ajax Post request in Django framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19333098/403-forbidden-error-when-making-an-ajax-post-request-in-django-framework)

Turns out it was the missing CSRF token that was causing problems. 
I just added

```
@csrf_exempt
```

on top of my update_like view and it works find now ;)

Answer (score 0):

So changing the URL worked as it was a post ajax request, but either change it to GET request in ajax or if you want to use POST request it is a good notion to pass csrf token.

So if you want the csrf token to be there, which is good for POST ajax methods, then you can remove the @csrf tag and in you java script write a method to get csrf token as suggested here

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax

Comment: Yup. I understand it is good practice to use csrf tokens but in this case I just wanted to get the ajax working since it's not sth that will go to prd

Comment: I am glad it worked, i faced the same problems once :). You can try GET too.